# Table Join in SQL not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, sql

My database design is seen as below:
[image: DB Design]

I'm interested in finding out what questions are in what questionnaire.

So I tried the below in order to output what questions were held inside of the questionnaire `Welcome Questionnaire`, however I get no results back in the rows:

```
SELECT `questionnaire`.`questionnaireName`, `questionnaireQuestions`.`questionID`,`question`.`question`
FROM `questionnaire`
INNER JOIN `questionnaireQuestions` ON `questionnaire`.`questionnaireID`=`questionnaireQuestions`.`questionID`
INNER JOIN `question` ON `questionnaire`.`questionnaireID` = `question`.`questionID`
WHERE `questionnaire`.`questionnaireName` = "Welcome Questionnaire";
```

I assumed I had to carry out 2 inner joins on the `questionnaireID`, could anyone highlight where I'm going wrong here.

As I should be getting this:

[image: questions should be returned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your table structure shown in the diagrams, you are joining on the wrong fields. You should join `questionnaireQuestions` to `questionnaire` on `questionnaireID` and `questionnaireQuestions` to `question` on `questionID` i.e.

```
SELECT `questionnaire`.`questionnaireName`, `questionnaireQuestions`.`questionID`,`question`.`question`
FROM `questionnaire`
INNER JOIN `questionnaireQuestions` ON `questionnaire`.`questionnaireID` = `questionnaireQuestions`.`questionnaireID`
INNER JOIN `question` ON `questionnaireQuestions`.`questionID` = `question`.`questionID`
WHERE `questionnaire`.`questionnaireName` = "Welcome Questionnaire";
```

Note that using table aliases can make your query easier to read; and backticks are only required to escape special characters in table/column names, so can in general be omitted:

```
SELECT qa.questionnaireName, qq.questionID, qs.question
FROM questionnaire qa
INNER JOIN questionnaireQuestions qq ON qa.questionnaireID = qq.questionnaireID
INNER JOIN question qs ON qq.questionID = qs.questionID
WHERE qa.questionnaireName = "Welcome Questionnaire";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, less typing...

```
SELECT a.questionnaireName
     , b.questionID
     , b.question
  FROM questionnaire a
  JOIN questionnaireQuestions ab
    ON ab.questionnaireID = a.questionnaireID 
  JOIN question b 
    ON b.questionID = ab.questionID 
 WHERE a.questionnaireName = "Welcome Questionnaire";
```

Comment: Do you know what, I had no idea I could call them whatever I could. That will save me SO much time!!!!

Comment: @T.C . . . You can assign tables whatever aliases you want.  About the worse choice are arbitrarily letters.  Use table abbreviations, such as `qn`, `qq`, and `q` in this case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ouch!